# How to return property of all elements of array inside MongoDB document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to return the `title` and `_id` properties of each element in my `trips` array of a user's document. I am attempting to use the aggregate pipeline but its my first time and the docs are overwhelming. It seems like all the examples show how to find a *single* piece of data. I basically want to return something like this:

```
[
  {title: "one", _id: 123},
  {title: "two", _id: 456},
  {title: "three", _id: 789},
]
```

From my document that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `find({})` as stated in [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find({})` for getting your expected result. In find query, you need to use a projection stage.

[Here the demo](https://www.humongous.io/app/playground/mongodb/KNekvmGFcKum)

Expected query

```
db.collection.find({},{_id:1,"trips.title":1,"trips._id":1});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ObjArray(array){
    let newArr = [];
    array.foreach(
    (obj) => {
        let newobj = {title: '', id:''}
        newobj.title = obj.title;
        newobj.id = obj.id;
        newArr.append(newobj);
    }
    );
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: this works too. but i  personally prefer to specify what data to receive rather than filter it after i receive a large chunk of it. thank you though